# Rails exclude a name "prefix" in model relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I have the models `Article`, `ArticleVote` and `ArticleComment`.

Is there any way to directly drop the prefixes like `article_` in the relations (rather than setings `class_name`, `foreign_key`, etc.)?

```
class Article
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :article_votes # Just call this "votes"
  has_many :article_comments # Just call this "comments"
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the idea to bully future code readers with hidden assumptions and magic aliasing does not sound to me good at all.

Comment: What's wrong with `has_many :votes, class_name: 'ArticleVote'`?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way.

You can specify any name you want but need to give the class name when it can not be inferred from the association name (and perhaps the foreign key, depending on how you named it):

```
class Article
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes, class_name: 'ArticleVote'
  has_many :comments, class_name: 'ArticleComment'
end
```

I don't see how this should be possible in any other way. How would rails know that you want the name built in another way for this specific association?

Comment: How would rails know? => The way it knows many other things: By convention.

Comment: Not sure I undestand, @ChristopherOezbek?

Rails knows by convention, yes. If you don't follow the convention then you need to configure it somehow. That configuration is done via class_name, foreign_key, ... options for the associations.

Comment: You said "I don't see how this should be possible in any other way." My answer: by adding conventions.